# How do I write Alt+Enter to a spreadsheet using PHP?

Tags: php, excel

I want to place Alt+Enter (line break) in a cell in an Excel spreadsheet. How do I write a character which is equivalent to Alt+Enter?

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is the escape-sequence for a line-break in a String.

Comment: i know \n as well as \r\n are used for line break.

Comment: So what is the problem you're facing? Show some code and be more specific if this is not your solution.

Comment: it's not for placing line break on screen. I've to put line break in excel sheet and in excel cell if you want to put line break you have to press Alt+Enter.

Comment: So i guess you're doing this using some kind of API or Library (since your question is tagged with [php]). So, show the code you're using.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a drupal module which provide a way to convert your data into excel sheet. for this you just need to put column name and it automatically create a excel sheet column. But in my column i wants to split the record by line break.

Comment: But somewhere along the process you'll need to add the content of a column, as a String i guess. Does inserting a line-break not work? Post some code!

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is for line break

`<br/>`is for html break

Comment: Sorry i wasn't able to explane my question properly. Please see the my conversation with Lukas Knuth and respond according to that.

Comment: try writing this `" & # 1 0 "` without spaces, and see if it breaks

Answer (score 0):

For Windows only (you mention Excel) the escape-sequence is `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  CHAR(10)

```
<string1> & CHAR(10) & <string2>
```

it will produce

```
<string1>
<string2>
```

in the excel cell.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to insert in following form:

```
"\="."\"string1\""."&char(10)&"."\"string2\""
```

After saving it xls through PHP

Apply wrap text on each column where your insert data